# Java ByteArrayInputStream.read result saved in byte array -- ASCII value gets saved

Tags: java

I have a byteArrayInputStream which I'm reading from `int i = bais.read(...)`  Let's say it returns 0.  I have an arraylist `ArrayList(Byte) myStorage` (couldn't figure out how to put <-byte-> in the code-tag).  I'm storing i into the `myStorage`. Like so: `myStorage.add((byte)i)`.  What get's store is not 0 but 48 (The ascii equivalent of 0).  How can I just store 0 into the byte array?  I think something silly is going on...

Comment: `myStorage.add((byte)i - (byte)'0')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you describe, `bais.read()` is returning 48, which is `'0'`, not 0. If you want to decode digit characters to their numeric values, you can use the [`Character.digit(digit, radix)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#digit%28char,%20int%29) method.

Unless by "`bais.read(...)`", you meant you are invoking the one- or three-argument overload of the `read()` method. In that case, `i` will contain the number of bytes read into the buffer that you passed.

Comment: I believe this is what had happened 0 was written as character to the file; as you say '0' which then was read as 48.  Boy, that was driving me mad...thanks